How to import hyp files into MATLAB?
I am trying to do OpenEMS simulation for a KiCad PCB.I am trying to follow the instructions from Tutorial: Importing with hyp2mat from the author.
I got this error when I was trying to import hyp files in MATLAB:
Unrecognized function or variable 'ImportHyperLynx'.


The Importing a printed circuit board part of the tutorial contains:

If an error message states 'InitCSX' or 'ImportHyperLynx' is undefined, you need to have another look at the install instructions:

The installation instructions note that addpath should be used to add the openEMS path to Matlab .
Where the ImportHyperLynx function is not part of a Mathworks toolbox, which is why the addpath is required to point at where openEMS has been installed.
I'm not sure if the repository is up to date, but found ImportHyperLynx.m which is the Matlab function.

I have path for OpenEMS. addpath('D:/openEMS/matlab');  but it still doesn't work as expected. And InitCSX(); works fine

Does the file D:/openEMS/matlab/ImportHyperLynx.m exist?

Nope. I don't know where it comes from

New error now.
hyp2mat.exe binary not found!
